# SQL Server 2008 Installation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I'm trying to install MS SQL Server 2008 on my Win 7 enabled laptop. I'm facing a problem while selecting the path to install. When I go on choose 'installation' and then when I click on 'New SQL Server stand alone installation or add features to an existing installation' it pops up a browse dialog box to select installation folder. I selected c:/program files/Microsoft SQL Server/ and tried all the folders under this folder. However, it gives me an error message saying

> c:/program files/Microsoft SQL Server/ is not a valid installation folder

I tried 1000 times but still I'm getting the same error. I already had SQL Server 2005 and I uninstalled it. After that I'm only trying to install MS SQL Server 2008. What is the problem here? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: please anybody could answer???

Comment: other people had this problem but no answer... few people resolved with a system restart...

Comment: @2GDev yeah exactly. i searched for it. could find a solution. is this a bug??? what do u mean by system restart??

Comment: Power ON -> Power OFF then Power ON. But i think is not a resolution! 
What's the version you're installing? Express Edition?

Comment: @2GDev lol. i thought sql server restart. thatz why i was wondering.  Yeah using exp edition. Before i install sql server 2005 i tried 2008. i could install that without any issues. but i could not proceed with installation since i do not have  VS 08 SP1. well let me try it using a restart.

Comment: Step by Step.. 
http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2009/03/30/sql-server-2008-express/
Maybe you have to install the Windows Powershell ?

Answer (score 19):

I recently had the same problem, I did the following:

Lets say you downloaded the `SQLServer2008R2SP1-KB2528583-x86-ENU file` to get SQL 2008 R2 and it won't accept the folder you choose. It is looking for your installation media AKA files to install your chosen option e.g. Upgrade or install.

**Right click on the SQLServer2008R2SP1-KB2528583-x86-ENU file, click on extract files** (winrar options). This will extract the install file giving you all the files that was compressed.

When SQL 2008 R2 Install Center ask you to choose the folder, select the extracted folder with all the files... problem solved!

Answer (score 12):

I think the error that you run into is just a case of bad choice of words from Microsoft. When they give the message: "select installation folder" they actually mean the drive that contains your Sql Server installation Dvd. I run into the same problem, and all I had to do was select the dvd drive and it worked.

Comment: This just worked for me running win 7 pro - upgrading from sql Server 2005 -> 2012

Answer (score 6):

Durden81 is right -  The error really means that it can't find the installation file. This seems to be a bug on versions of SQL Sever downloaded from internet or installed as part of the Visual Web Developer Express 2010 bundle.

I was searching for an answer to the same question and came across this. Unfortunately the other replies did not work for me. What did work was the following:

- Go to the control panel and uninstall everything to do with "Microsoft SQL Server 2008" and any other version of SQL Sever you might have.
- Restart your computer and go to the Microsoft Download center (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/default.aspx) and search for: Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Express with Tools
- Unpack this and run the installation.
- Restart your computer before running Visual Studio again

Answer (score 2):

While I don't think this has ever been a requirement, since it's not really clear from your question exactly which component is choking on the path, I suggest trying a simpler path with no spaces, e.g. "C:\MSSQL\" ...

Comment: @jp2code Ok, I'll bite. What does "does not work" mean? What path did you try? What error do you get? People can't fix "does not work."

Comment: I don't know. I've got Sql2008 Express as part of VS2010, and Management Studio working with our SQL Server, but I'm trying (without success) to get a local instance created using a backup. When I do, SQL Server 2008 R2 Installation Center keeps asking me for the media. I extracted it like in Marc's post, and moved all of it to "C:\MSSQL", but I still get the message that "X is not a valid installation folder." (X, it seems, can be anything)

Comment: I even get the same thing when I try to run the **System Configuration Checker** in the **Planning** section. UGH! Microsoft, you should change your name to UberHard!

Comment: @jp2code When your toilet doesn't work, do you just say "toilet's broke?"

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Even that's more specific than "bathroom doesn't work."

Comment: That's it exactly (bathroom doesn't work)! I suspect the reason the OP never accepted an answer is because none of these solutions worked for him either. So, did the earlier comment answer your question, Aaron? If I understood what Microsoft was wanting, I could at least approach the problem, but all it tells me is "'Folder' is not a valid installation folder" for whatever folder I move all of the installation files to (yes, even C:\MSSQL).

Comment: @jp2code I think you should create a new question where you can specify all of those details, including exactly what installation you have (x86, x64, with SP, etc) and exactly what steps you are following. For one, this question was asked three years ago, is relevant to a different version of SQL Server than the one you're using, and who knows why they never accepted an answer. It's not required.

Comment: Done. I would be happy if this detailed question gave you any insights into my problem. I tried to be VERY thorough in listing what I've tried and what is not working. http://stackoverflow.com/q/22050470/153923

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with Durden81. It's actually the problem regarding the path. It wants you to choose the path where the sql server setup file lies. Give the correct path of the setup file, whether it is in DVD or in a drive.

Answer (score 0):

Give the path of installer, this helped me.
For example if you have the SQL server installer on C:\SQL SERVER\Enterprise Edition\setup.exe
Provide the same path, this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because the installation package was located on a network/virtual location. To resolve this, I found the correct path (by asking IT) and ran the .exe as administrator. All is good.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when clicking on the app in "Add/Remove Programs" to add features to the current install. Yes, you can proceed as @Marc Uberstein's answer, but re-running the ENU with a double click should get you where you need to go, without extracting, bypassing the "Add/Remove Programs" piece altogether. Not sure from your question if that is the route you took to arrive at the error, but this was the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

It depend on what error prompt you are getting. If it's saying "wrong folder" or something of that nature, then it's the folder that's causing the error. Just delete all the folders of `sqlserver` on your computer and restart and it should work, or you can go to property of that `sqlserver` folder and in advanced and un-check the compress and re-run. It should definitely work.