# Installing and creating instance of SQL Server 2012

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2012, failed-installation

I am running `SQLManagementStudio_x86_2012_ENU.exe` to install SQL Server 2012. I came across a problem and I was hunged on it too long.

I have seen the same problem in SO and they are give a solution for that. I also over come that problem but again stuck again in half way through. So I am going to ask this again(not a spam)

Problem: When I ran above mentioned exe it was installed fine, Then I tried to create a instance of the server. I used  `SQL Server Installation Center` in configuration tools. then I selected new SQL Server and it asks me to select the `SQL Server Installation Media`. I selected `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server` but it was invalied.

then I figured out that it is asking for the Installation media itself. So I extracted the .exe file to a folder and selected that path. that was taken as a valid media.
I refered to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569508/problem-in-sql-server-2008-installation).

some have mentioned that this was a bug [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/sqlgetstarted/thread/33153123-493e-4bfa-89a3-180c481b5fe4).

[image]

when I clicked next it gives the following error. so that I can not proceed and create a instance. Can some one help me on this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried lot of things to come up with a solution for this. As you can see in the picture, there are only 2 check boxes which are already checked and disabled. This is not the right .exe file to run(I was unable to create a server instance using this). I downloaded the right SQL server installation file from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763.aspx).

There are several .exe files that gives different functionality enhancements. I chose SQL server with tools which is about 1GB. I did not have to uninstall the existing sql server installation. I installed this and it worked fine. I will post back if I found a way to create a SQL server form the given installation. If you have the same problem as described above, most probably you are using the wrong .exe file.

Good luck with your fix.

Comment: right the SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe will solve this issue.