# Launching SQL Server 2008 Express from VS2010 in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

My laptop has Windows 7, x64 bit, and was built this past December (2 months ago). It has **Microsoft Visual Studio 2010** installed with **SQL Server 2008 Express**, but I had not used "Sql2008" before on this PC.

**SQL Server Management Studio** *has* been installed all that time, and I use it to connect to our company's instance of SQL Server.

Now, I need to do some development and debugging on a large stored procedure that is not returning the data we expect. I got a backup of the database  **companyDB.bak** and moved that to my Win7x64 laptop in this folder: `C:\Temp\companyDB.bak`.

[image: companyDB.bak]

I open **SQL Server Management Studio** and select **(local)** and click "Connect":

[image: (local)]

After some time, I get error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

[image: Error 2]

I do some research and found this helpful link: [SQL SERVER – FIX : ERROR : (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 – Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: )](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)

His first step is to make sure SQL Server is running, which it seems to be:

[image: SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)]

Next, it says to make sure I am using TCP/IP Port 1433. When I looked, it seemed all of mine were BLANK, so I changed them so that all use Port 1433, then Stopped and Restarted the service:

[image: TCP Port 1433]

OK, now I can get my local instance to start up.

When I attempted to restore the database using my "companyDB.bak" file, I get an error saying the database I am restoring from is newer than I am saving it to:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.2531. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

[image: SmoExtended]

So, I downloaded **SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe** from here: from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438

During installation, I get this error saying that it can't install until **SQL Server 2005 Express Tools" are removed:

[image: SQL Server 2005 Express Tools]

Now below, if you will notice, I did a search of the items installed under my computer, and the only thing there is with "2005" in the title is **VC++ 2005 Redistributable**:

[image: VC++ 2005 Redistributable]

So, I cancelled the installation and started it again, this time selecting the "Upgrade from SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008" option, but I got the same error message.

I do not seem to be able to continue.

Obviously, some of my installed applications need **VC++ 2005 Redistributable**, or I would not have installed it a few months ago.

### How do I proceed?

**[UPDATE]:**

Following Davide Mauri's [SQL Server 2008 R2 Installation and the Phantom of SQL Server 2005 Express](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/davide_mauri/archive/2010/05/04/sql-server-2008-r2-installation-and-the-phantom-of-sql-server-2005-express.aspx) blog, I searched for the term `Sql2005SsmsExpressFacet` in the log file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\yyyymmdd_hhmmss\Detail.txt".

It only pointed to a single registry entry (where his pointed at two): ""

```
Init rule target object: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.Sql2005SsmsExpressFacet
Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey 
Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ShellSEM
Rule 'Sql2005SsmsExpressFacet' detection result: SQL 2005 Ssms EE installed=True
Evaluating rule        : Sql2005SsmsExpressFacet
Rule running on machine: 5000-C6E8-1
Rule evaluation done   : Failed
Rule evaluation message: The SQL Server 2005 Express Tools are installed. To continue, remove the SQL Server 2005 Express Tools.
```

But, my registry does not even HAVE that directory:

[image: registry]

**[UPDATE 2]:**

OK, so our IT guy has given me the full blown **SQL Server 2008 R2** CD to install, but I am still hitting this same roadblock with it thinking that **SQL Server 2005 Express tools** are still installed - so I can not move forward.

[image: SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup]

Comment: with express, the instance name is always SQLEXPRESS. now, you cannot restore a DB with a different SKU or a newer version of SQL Server to a lower version. This is not a "bug" or anything. it is intentional and always has been

Comment: Are you sure about that? I **know** I have installed an **SQL Server 2000** database to SQL Server Express before, and I want to say I've done this with **SQL Server 2008** before as well.

Comment: Restoring a newer version database to an older version using a .bak has never been doable.  You can instead Generate Scripts off the newer one and set the compatibility to 2008, then run those scripts on the older one.  That is the only way.

Comment: @ahmed....the default instance name is "SQLEXPRESS".. You can override it.

Comment: @granadaCoder - indeed. I was saying by default is always SQLEXPRESS - I should have been clearer. but OOB it is SQLEXPRESS

Comment: I still can not get SQL Server 2008 to install because of this *SQL Server 2005 Express tools* (see [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vvYxH.jpg) above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I did the following:

- Uninstall all of the SQL Management Studio instances I had
- reboot
- Install SQL Server 2008 (not the Express version)
- reboot

Tada!

I guess Microsoft likes selling their product, and it worked.